# Getting coordinates of an object in corona SDK game

Tags: lua, coronasdk

In my corona application, I have a character that can `fly` during the gameplay. This is accomplished by touching a `jump/fly button`. I have achieved this as:

```
local c=false  -- Flag residing fly/jump button state

function up:touch(event)
  if event.phase == "began"
    c=true 
  elseif event.phase =="ended" then 
    c=false
  end
end

function jump(event)
  if c  then
    character:applyForce (0,-300, character.x, character.y)
  end
end

up:addEventListener( "touch", up )
Runtime:addEventListener("enterFrame", jump)
```

Now I need to disable the button until the character reaches the ground again. For that, I've decided to check the character Y position on runtime, but don't know how to do that. I'm not sure whether this is the correct idea or not. If you have a better option then please suggest me that also.

**Problem:**

1. I want to make function that would calculate object.x and object.y coordinates and saving them to x and y variables all the time when app is running.
2. I'm starter in lua, is it there any way to program in c++ in corona?

Now I want to check disable the jump button once pressed.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish by this?

Comment: the thing is, that I want to set button for jump only to be able to pressed, if the character is on the ground. So i need a y coordinate of character to see if jump button is able to be pressed..

Comment: Couldn't you just check the character's `y` when you need it?

Comment: If you know C++ you will find Lua straightforward. The Corona docs are excellent. Show some effort and try something based on the docs. Show what you have tried then we can help you.

Comment: where i should put the statement? i have function to checking if button was pressed.. if button was pressed some variable value become true and that's how the other function knows that character must move... if i put the statement to check (if character coordinate is the same as ground) the coordinate of y in first function button just stop to work.. so i would like to write coordinates on screen to se what's happening with values... it would hellped me also with some other solutions in app..

Comment: i have change my original post and fill it with code..

Answer (score 2):

This does what you are asking

```
local objX, objY
local obj

--this runs every frame
local function onEnterFrame( event )
   objX = obj.x
   objY = obj.y 
end

Runtime:addEventListener( "enterFrame", onEnterFrame )
```

And for the C++ part, I don't think you can do that, Corona's scripting is in Lua. [read this to learn Lua](http://tylerneylon.com/a/learn-lua/)